# are you allowed to say Beth EL

Tags: halacha

A shul which is named Beth EL  being that El is God's name am I allowed to say it
sholom as stated in the talmud is God's name as well but u don't see people refraining from saying it
I personally think that it whould be ok being that u don't have gods name in mind rather just the nickname of the shul. like Daniel.

Comment: mendel, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] this post so that it's in clear, grammatically correct, standard English? The easier it is to read, 1) the more likely it'll get good answers, and 2) the more valuable your question plus its answers will be to future readers. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it a duplicate? The other one focuses on writing while this focuses on pronouncing. It may be reasonable to assume the same standard applies to both, but is that enough to be a duplicate (e.g. Alex wrote at the end of his answer there, `I don't know whether this would also affect how it should be spoken (when not saying a complete pasuk)`)?

Comment: @Fred Seems like a duplicate to me. Writing is an example there ("e.g."), not the entire question.

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps. I suppose I read that question too quickly the first time around.